# Create array of variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the M-file "matrixT.m", i wrote the function matrixT to generate a n*3 matrix like that

```
function T=matrixT(alpha,n)
T=zeros(3,n);
for i=1:n
    T(1,i)=cos(alpha(i));
    T(2,i)=sin(alpha(i));
    T(3,i)=sin(alpha(i)-i*pi/2);
end
```

Then i use it in my main M-file

```
alpha=sym('alpha');
V=subs(hessian(det(matrixT(alpha,3)),alpha),alpha,alpha0);
```

but there are many error. Can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in the assignment: `T(1,i)=cos(alpha(i));`. You have assigned `alpha` to be a symbolic variable, but then you try to assign it to an array of doubles and MATLAB complains. Is it possible to evaluate the value of `alpha` before attempting to place it inside the array `T`?

Comment: How can I assign an array of variables for alpha?

Comment: You'll probably want to use your `subs` function earlier to substitute a real value for `alpha` before you try to put it into the `T` array.

Comment: the problem is, i must assign the vector alpha (n-dimensional) and take the hessian? can i do it? Could you make an example for me?

Comment: `alpha` is not a vector, it's a symbolic variable. If you have to calculate the Hessian multiple times using different values of `alpha`, I would recommend placing the Hessian calculation inside a `for` loop, and in each loop iteration set the value of `alpha` and then calculate what you want.

Comment: If you only have one value for `alpha`, then don't make it a symbolic variable. Just use the value of `alpha` to make your `T` matrix and everything should be fine. However, if you have multiple values for `alpha`, you'll need to evaluate `V` in a loop because it will take on different values for different values of `alpha`.

Comment: Is it possible when i  create new variables in a loop (i must index the variable??) which function in Matlab i can use?